# Flutter Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.lock' (OS Error: EL parametro no es correcto)

Tags: flutter

acabo de descargar flutter en mi pc y me aparece este cuando cuando quiero ejecutar el comando "flutter doctor" en la carpeta "C:\src\flutter\bin" que es donde tengo flutter, ya he definido las variables de entorno y tambien he instalado Git, pero el error sigue apareciendo.

Este es el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las variables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bueno podrías probar utilizando el comando `flutter pub cache repair`

De igual manera los pasos para instalar Flutter (De manera global no solo en esa carpeta) son estos:

1. Descargas el archivo .zip en https://flutter.dev/ y lo colocas en algún disco duro de tu elección.
2. Lo descomprimes y entras a la carpeta, veras la carpeta 'flutter' la cortas y la pegas en la raíz del disco duro.
3. Entra a la carpeta hasta flutter\bin y aquí copias la dirección y luego a las variables de entorno en "PATH" la agregas, he visto que algunos suelen colocarla de la siguiente manera "C:Users\usuario\src\flutter\bin".
4. Ahora abre la Powershell y comprueba con flutter --version
5. Y si hiciste todo bien ya el flutter doctor debería servir